# Swift - Setting a label border using border width and color is working, but setting when setting a specific side the frame width is off

Tags: ios, swift, border, calayer

I am trying to put a border around my labels just on certain sides so that they do not overlap. Here is the code I am using: cell.jobAddress.layer.borderColor =

```
`cell.jobAddress.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.jobAddress.layer.borderWidth = 2
        cell.jobPlaceBid.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.jobPlaceBid.layer.borderWidth = 2
`
```

and here is what it looks like: 
[image]

As you can see, the bottoms and tops overlap. So, I have been using this code to try to add borders only to specific sides :

```
    extension CALayer {

    func addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge, color: UIColor, thickness: CGFloat) {

        let border = CALayer()

        switch edge {
        case UIRectEdge.top:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: thickness)
            break
        case UIRectEdge.bottom:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.height - thickness, width: self.frame.width, height: thickness)
            break
        case UIRectEdge.left:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: thickness, height: self.frame.height)
            break
        case UIRectEdge.right:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width - thickness, y: 0, width: thickness, height: self.frame.height)
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor;

        self.addSublayer(border)
    }

}
```

and then this to implement it:

```
cell.jobAddress.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.left, color: UIColor.black, thickness: 2)
    cell.jobAddress.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.right, color: UIColor.black, thickness: 2)
    cell.jobAddress.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.top, color: UIColor.black, thickness: 2)
    cell.jobAddress.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: UIColor.black, thickness: 2)
    cell.jobPlaceBid.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.left, color: UIColor.black, thickness: 2)
    cell.jobPlaceBid.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.right, color: UIColor.black, thickness: 2)
    cell.jobPlaceBid.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: UIColor.black, thickness: 2)
```

Here is what this looks like:

[image]

What do you think could be wrong? I wait until the labels have values before adding the borders. I set the width just by making the labels 10 points from each side.

Thank you in advance, I know this is a long post!

Comment: Are you using autolayout for labels?

Comment: @RajeshkumarR I'm using reset to suggested constraints. But even if I manually do it, add every constraint possible, the frame.width is incorrectr

Comment: Try calling `cell.setNeedsLayout()` and `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` methods before implementing `addBorder` method.

Comment: Actually they are *not* overlapping. They are contiguous - meaning if you have a 1pt border all around, you have 2pts (1 each) on labels side-by-side. One thing you can do *is* overlap them. In this case, move each label 1pt up (or down), adding another point for each in the series.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR That worked! Thank you so much! This has been giving me such a headache over the last few days, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto layout hasn't had the time to layout your views by the time you call `addBorder`.

```
cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

forces a calculation of UILabel dimensions causing the expected values to get in `addBorder` method.

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

@RaheshkumarR answered the question in the comments, I am only posting it here for visibility when others run into the problem. The solution is to use cell.mylabel.setNeedsLayout() and cell.mylabel.layoutIfNeeded().

I hope this helps!